# python pulp script error when executing in console

Tags: python, anaconda, ide, solver, pulp

I installed pulp via anaconda distribution on Ubuntu 20.04. For developing my python code I use the WingIDE. Everything runs fine in the IDE.
However, if I execute my script directly in the console via

`.../anaconda/bin/pyton myscript.py`

I get the following error

```
  File "/home/icke/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py", line 1899, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
```

Why is that and how can I fix this error?

The pulp test `.../anaconda/bin/pulptest` runs flawlessly.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try activating your conda environment rather than using the full path to the python interpreter.

Comment: how can I activate the environment. I found another solution. I install the coinor-cbc library via `sudo apt install coinor-cbc` which did the job.